# telerik radMenu shows through to a radWindow

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, telerik

I have a radMenu on the main site.master form which shows on a page.  The page has a radGrid with a button to open a radWindows that shows a report.  When the radWindow opens everything works great but the radMenu shows through onto the Window.  How do I prevent the menu from showing through on the window.

[image]
<sub>(source: [rjmueller.net](http://rjmueller.net/SitesImages/temp/menushowsthrough.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default RadMenu z-index is 7000 whereas the default RadWindow z-index is 3000 ([reference here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/controlling-absolute-positioning-with-zindex.html)). Change the z-index of the RadMenu to be less than the RadWindow (or the contrary as you prefer).

```
<telerik:RadMenu runat="server" style="z-index: 2900" />
```

Comment: An even lower z-index was needed for me because the RadMenu was still showing above a RadGrid's PopUp edit form (which has a z-index of 2500.) You need to use the Telerik reference link in this answer if 2900 does not fix things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Julien is right - more info can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/controlling-absolute-positioning-with-zindex.html).

Note that if you use a RadWindowManager (instead of standalone RadWindow controls), you should set the z-index to the manager itself.